# target="_self" taking link to home page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

This should be so simple it's driving me crazy!

Working in Wordpress using a shortcode php insert-er. Page works great except this code doesn't stay on the same page where the link is pointing.

```
<a target="_self" href="#Lighter+Beers">Lighter Beers</a>
```

Even when I hover over the link, I see the correct address in at the bottom of the browser [www.oddsideales.com/all-beverages-on-tap/#Lighter+Beers....but](http://www.oddsideales.com/all-beverages-on-tap/#Lighter+Beers....but) after clicking, the browser url shows [www.oddsideales.com/#Lighter+Beers](http://www.oddsideales.com/#Lighter+Beers)

Is there some way to test why the url changes?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try getting rid of the `target`.

Comment: I actually did...and it comes back!

Comment: Was able to find a piece of script that was automatically adding the _self. Checked the output and the target is gone...yet it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Installed Easy Smooth Scrolling plugin, and for some reason my urls stopped changing. So the three things that fixed my issues were...

Creating an urlencode that properly encoded my query results

```
$heading_old=$heading;
$divider = 1;
$path = urlencode($heading_old);
$items.="<h3 id='$path' class='category_h' style='width: 100%; display: flow-root; margin: 10px 10px; font-weight: 600; color: #bcd63a;'>$heading_old</h3>";
}
```

Changed my anchor links to match the urlencoded output

```
<ul class="nav2">
  <li><a target="_self" href="#Darker+Beers">Darker Beers</a></li>
  <li><a target="_self" href="#Lighter+Beers">Lighter Beers</a></li>
  <li><a target="_self" href="#Hoppy+Beers">Hoppy Beers</a></li>
  <li><a target="_self" href="#Wild+%26+Sour">Wild and Sour</a></li>
  <li><a target="_self" href="#Wines+%26+Cider">Wines and Cider</a></li>
</ul>
```

Lastly added this to avoid scrolling up behind my header

```
:target:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Problem solved!